# Removing ink/toner from smudges on thick paper

Tags: cleaning, stationery, paper

I have already looked at this [question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4101/how-to-remove-ink-from-paper), and whilst some of the answers might suit my case, I thought I should put this to the community, as my situation is slightly different.

I printed out some schematics onto 210gsm paper (our printer is a HP Laserjet P2035). The ink and toner has struggled to take to the paper. Now as I have been working on cutting out these shapes, the original ink is rubbing off to some extent and it is creating smudges on the reverse of the paper, either from my matt cutter or my hands (much like newspaper print).

So of course the question is which is the best method to attempt to remove these smudges.

Photos of front and reverse for referece:

[image: model1]
[image: model2]

**EDIT**

Sorry I should add I was slightly wary about adding a solution to the paper for fear of buckling it (acetone for example).

Comment: You can ignore the advice in the up-voted and accepted answer in the link you include in your question. There is ***nothing*** there of value for you. The advice in the second answer details a technique (gouache to cover mistakes) used for many years by graphics professionals that works perfectly but is overkill for your situation.

Comment: Thanks. I could actually use a test piece and try out some different techniques. Of course I don't want to ruin my actual model.

Comment: It sounds as if the HP Laserjet fuser is not at the proper temperature to melt the toner for a good bond. This is good news if you want to remove the stuff.

Comment: BTW, if you fold the paper the opposite way, the ink will be on the ***inside*** of the shape you're making instead of the outside. When the ink is on the inside, it won't show and doesn't have to be removed. It's neater and easier to fold the paper differently. It doesn't have to be removed at all but that didn't answer your question.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure then if all the pieces would join together. I am working with fairly complex polygons.

Comment: And actually since I worked on this I collaborated with a model maker for him to construct the models for me and he did a much better job than I could!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal white plastic eraser should do the trick. As you pointed out, the ink is already smudging so any reasonable effort to remove it will work. Make sure to keep the eraser clean to avoid working the toner into the paper surface.

Another possibility would be to apply a thin layer of paper (rubber) cement over the smudges. After it dries, use a natural rubber pick-up square (sometimes called a mouse) to remove the cement and smudges.
 It contains no water so it will not distort the paper. It dries quickly.
**Note:** Do **not** use "one-coat" cement which will be more difficult to remove if not impossible. I use "Best-Test" brand paper cement. A small bottle comes with its own brush applicator.

A third possibility would be to use a very sharp knife such as a single-edge razor blade or x-acto knife (with #10 General Purpose blade which is curved to avoid gouging or cutting the surface). Use the appropriate blade nearly perpendicular to the surface to gently scrape the toner off the paper. Pull the blade toward you lightly and repeatedly until the mark is gone. This is a make-shift knife eraser that is used on parchment and other such surfaces. When done properly, there is little or no trace of the mark on the piece.
Note that the knife eraser needs a bit of attention when used on folds, creases, or scores that make the surface uneven.